# Replace a field only for lines beginning with a string with a defined string

Tags: awk, replace

Here is the file I need to deal with.

```
ENR1;203023;0000;H606626;001505;EL;00;1234;0000100;00;00;201346100;H6022418;
ENR6;000218;130155;000;00;201443;000000000;000000000;000000000;000000000;
ENR1;203357;0000;H606626;001653;EL;01;2546;0000800;00;00;201346100;H6022418;
ENR6;000218;130155;000;00;201503;000000000;000000000;000000000;000000000;
ENR6;001811;150316;000;00;201624;000000000;000000000;000000000;000000000;
ENR1;203385;0000;H606625;000615;EL;00;5861;0000100;00;00;201346100;H6022418;
```

I must substitute field 7 of each line. If the value is `00`, then I must set it to `01`.
But only for lines whose first field is `ENR1!`

```
awk -F';' -v OFS=';' 'NR>=1{sub("00","01",$7)}1' file > result
```

This works but also remplace field $7 with lines beginning with ENR6.

How adding the condition (only lines starting with ENR1?)

Answer (score 1):

I would try

```
awk -F';' -v OFS=';' '$7 == "00" && $1 == "ENR1" { $7 = "01" } {print} ' file > result
```

where

- `$7 == "00" && $1 == "ENR1" { $7 = "01" }` only applied to line starting with `ENR1`, having seventh field equel to `00`
- `$7 = "01"` set 7th field to 01
- `{ print }` print every line, including ENR1's after change.
- you may wish to keep `NR>=1` test if real file has a one-line header.

Comment: The check there isn't needed imho. The "shorter" version would be something as: `awk -F';' -vOFS=";" '/ENR1/{$7="01"}1' filename`

Answer (score 0):

Short ***sed*** approach:

```
sed -E 's/^(ENR1;([^;]+;){5})00;/\101;/' file
```

The output:

```
ENR1;203023;0000;H606626;001505;EL;01;1234;0000100;00;00;201346100;H6022418;
ENR6;000218;130155;000;00;201443;000000000;000000000;000000000;000000000;
ENR1;203357;0000;H606626;001653;EL;01;2546;0000800;00;00;201346100;H6022418;
ENR6;000218;130155;000;00;201503;000000000;000000000;000000000;000000000;
ENR6;001811;150316;000;00;201624;000000000;000000000;000000000;000000000;
ENR1;203385;0000;H606625;000615;EL;01;5861;0000100;00;00;201346100;H6022418;
```

---

- `^(ENR1;([^;]+;){5})00;` - captures lines starting with `ENR1` followed by 5 fields `([^;]+;){5}` and the 7th field `00;`

Comment: -E parameter seems not to be recognized by UNIX (AIX) ... ?